# How to get first non-zero entry across all columns and sum it row-by-row for a data-frame?

Tags: python, pandas

---

Say I have a table like this-

```
    User1  User2  User3  User4  User5  User6  User7  User8
w1      1      1      0      0      0      1      0      0
w2      0      1      0      0      1      1      0      0
w3      0      0      1      0      1      1      0      0
w4      1      1      1      1      0      0      0      0
w5      1      0      1      0      1      1      0      1
w6      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
```

I want an output table that finds the first 1 for each column and sums it for every week, so something like this-

(I basically want to find the number of first time users, by week)

```
 Column
w1      3     -ie User1, User2, User6
w2      1     -ie User5
w3      1     -ie User3
w4      1     -ie User4   
w5      1     -ie User8
w6      1     -ie User7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `idxmax` and `value_counts`

```
s=df.idxmax().value_counts()
s
w1    3
w2    1
w6    1
w3    1
w4    1
w5    1
dtype: int64
```